# How one compose know other compose position and also how it can fill the remaining space available?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have one long doubt. I will say what it is. Lets, say i have a column compose where i want to put two rows or columns with different color(for identification) so it becomes two section now. Now inside main column compose i create first column with height 400 dp and fillMaxWidth, (MY QUESTION IS) how to put the second column inside the main column so that it fills the rest of the space(height) available in the main column compose without specifying the remaining height(because i donot the remaining height). I want the both column should be visible inside the main column compose.

Like to say the second column should know where the first column ends and also it should know to fill the rest of the space.

[image: Descripting scenario in Image]

Comment: apply `Modifier.weight(1f)` for the second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Modifier.weight(1f)` like so:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestColumn() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            text = "Column 1",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(400.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Column 2",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
        )
    }
}
```